# Find Longest Increasing Subsequence with adjacent elements having a difference of at least k

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, time-complexity

Given an array `A` of size `n` and a number `k`, find the size of the Longest Increasing Subsequence (say, `B[]`) where `B[i+1] >= B[i] + k`.

```
2 <= n <= 10^6
A[i] <= 10^5
k <= 10^5
```

Sample Input:

```
A = [1, 3, 1, 4, 5, 9, 12]
k = 2
The LIS in this case will be: [1, 3, 5, 9, 12]
Answer = 5
```

How to solve in complexity `O(N * log(N))` (or better)? I have described my `O(N^2 * log(N))` approach below:

I'll use a Data Structure similar to `std::multiset` (in C++). `std::multiset` will ensure that all the elements in the multiset will be sorted at any point of time.

I'll make a multiset of pairs `std::multiset <pair <int, int> > V` where the first element in the pair will be the element from array `A` and the second element will be the size of the Longest Increasing Subsequence such that the LIS ends at the first element of the pair. Also, in each case, the first pair in the multiset will be `<-∞, 0>`.

```
int answer() {

    multiset < pair < int, int> > V;
    V.insert(<-∞, 0>);
    final_answer = 1

    for (element e) in A {
        maximum_possible = 1

        for (pair p) in V {
            if (p.first > e - k)
                break;
            maximum_possible = max(p.second + 1, maximum_possible)
        }
        V.insert(<A[i], maximum_possible>)
        final_answer = max(final_answer, maximum_possible)
    }

    return final_answer;
}
```

Comment: When you can do it in O(n^2), why go for O(n^2 log(n))? Also, time complexity will remain quadratic in this case. You can sort the elements but it will change their order.

Comment: I was thinking of somehow restricting the size of the set to be traversed for each element of array, in which I could not succeed. So this approach is based on that thinking.

Comment: Sorting the elements will change their order. How can you make sure you preserve the order?

Comment: @SomeDude I am storing the answer for `ith` element in the set i.e the maximum length increasing subsequence with constraints having `ith` element as the last element, they need not be in any sorted order while storing the results.

Comment: Your algorithm doesn't seem to work. Its design is dubious. Why a multiset? Why set is not satisfactory? Moreover, why do you need to update all of the subsequences when the longest one would be enough? An ordered map seems to be the right data structure in this case. Have you tried the standard LIS algorithm with a modified condition?

Comment: @n.m. I get your point but multiset was used to have an answer for all indices which may have same element as well. I could have ignored them as if I have seen that element before then the new one can't be better but indeed I chose this to have answer for all indices.

Comment: What is the meaning of having e.g. (17,3) in the multiset three times?

Comment: @n.m. If `17,3` is present thrice in the multiset that means `17` was present thrice in the input array. Without losing generality I stored the answer for all the indices.

Comment: You are not storing indices at all, just lengths. The three (17,3)s are indistinguishable. There's no reason to store them all.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in `O(N^2)` by using standard dynamic programming for LIS:
Only change is instead of `nums[i] > nums[j]` in the if condition just change it to `nums[i] - nums[j] >= K`

```
    public int lengthOfLISAtLeastKUsingDP(int[] nums, int K) {
        int[] dp = new int[nums.length+1];
        Arrays.fill(dp, 1);
        int ans = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++ ) {
            for ( int j = 0; j < i; j++ ) {
                if ( nums[i] - nums[j] >= K ) {
                    dp[i] = Math.max( dp[i], 1 + dp[j] );
                }
            }
            ans = Math.max( ans, dp[i] ); 
        }
        return ans;
    }
```

Having said that, I believe you could do it in `O(N*log(N))` like this:

1. Create an empty list.
2. Add first element to list.
3. Traverse the list, if you encounter an element which is bigger than the last element of the list by more than or equal to K, add it to the list.
4. If it is not, then do a binary search in the list for that element, if it is found there is nothing to do.
5. Otherwise look at the insertion point. The insertion point is either greater than size of list or lesser than it.
6. If it is greater than size AND if the difference between that element and last element in the list is greater than K, add it to list.
7. If the insertion point is zero, just replace the 0th element.
8. But if the insertion point is not zero, look at its left element. If their difference is greater than or equal to K, insert the element there.
9. The size of resulting list is the answer.

```java
public int lengthOfLISAtLeastK(int[] nums, int K) {
    if ( nums == null ) return 0;
    if ( nums.length <= 1 ) return nums.length;
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(nums.length);
    list.add( 0, nums[0] );
    for ( int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++ ) {
        if ( nums[i] - list.get( list.size() - 1 ) >= K ) {
            list.add( nums[i] );
        } else  {
            int index = Collections.binarySearch( list, nums[i] );
            if ( index >= 0 && index < nums.length ) {
                list.set( index, nums[i] );
            } else {
                if ( -index - 1 > list.size() - 1 ) {
                    if ( nums[i] - list.get(list.size()-1) >= K ) {
                        list.add(nums[i]);
                    }
                } else {
                     if ( -index - 1 == 0 ) {
                        list.set(-index-1, nums[i]);
                    } else if ( nums[i] - list.get(-index-2) >= K ) {
                        list.set(-index-1, nums[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return list.size();
}
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time following the code and the explanation; what do you mean by "insertion point" and what do all those conditions signify? I'm getting the feeling you're basically presorting the input array, then kind of greedily finding the largest wanted subsequence in that sorted array instead of the original.

Comment: @G.Bach "insertion point"- See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,%20T)). If it is negative that means the element is not present in the list. Now we need to check if we can insert that element somewhere in our list. If the -index-1 is greater than size that means no other element is smaller than the one we are searching so it has to be added to end- but only if it is >= last element by K. Similar approach holds with one which has to be inserted in the middle - we need to look to left and then replace and I am not presorting.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it similarly to normal LIS problem. The algorithm:

```
 1. Make an empty dynamic array (or anything that you can push back elements into in O ( 1 ) and that gives you access to any element in O(1) ), let's call it DP
 2. For every number v in the input array:
      3. Search DP array for a value smaller or equal to v - k and set a variable id as it's id number in the DP array (using binary search, if it does not exist, set id as -1)
      4. Increase id by 1
      5. If size of DP is equal id, insert there a new value, that is v
          Else if DP[id] > v, change it to v.
 6. Return size of DP.
```

That's it, O( n log n).